# setTimeout for AJAX Request only if file not available in browser cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-cache

I have a web page where I've used setTimeout to load script files in DOM after 5 seconds after "DOMContentLoaded" fires.

It happens every time I load/reload the page. Of course the files are cached in browser next time onwards but the point here is **"It takes 5 seconds every time for loading the files into DOM, because of setTimeout"**

I want to reduce eliminate this waiting if the files are already in cache-making the functions available to the user as soon as possible.

I want to set the timeout only if the file is not available in cache, and load it immediately otherwise!

> Is there any way to check browser cache if a file is available in cache?

I completely understand that it is browser's job to do so but I want to improve the UX by eliminating that 5 seconds wait on every load. It should happen for very first time.

Comment: why don't you make use of localStorage or indexed db?

Comment: @Jai why should I do that? need more explanation!

Comment: Hmm, how you want to check if user disable cache?

Comment: @Veniamin nice catch! well, that would be another use case, and a point to consider too.

Comment: Why that timeout in the first place? Even if I don’t have the resources in question cached already, I’d expect the site to load all stuff as quickly as possible. Why introduce an artificial timeout to slow that process down even more …?

Comment: @Veniamin I guess the file won't be available if cache is disabled, so already handled!

Comment: if you are clear cache before made a request

Comment: @CBroe these files are not responsible for page render or style. They contains bindings on DOM elements and other things required only after page load.

Comment: That still doesn’t explain how a five second timeout would be beneficial. If the user doesn’t notice the effect of the timeout – then it should not matter if it is present on _all_ pages, no matter if the user visited other parts of your site before and/or has script files cached.

Comment: @CBroe sometimes they notice, so it's like if they click somewhere before 5 seconds-nothing happens! This is what I want to sort out.

Comment: Well then you should probably rather implement a load handler for those scripts, and only make the elements in question react to clicks after that, or show the user a message if they click somewhere already before the scripts are loaded.